# How to get data from one model to other

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have two models
name

user model 
result model

user model contains email, password, sign_in_time etc
 result model contains user_email and result fields

I want to fetch email from user model into result model's user_email fields

how can I achieve this

That's the schema files of both

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,   default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                         null: false
    t.boolean  "admin",                  limit: 1
    t.boolean  "superadmin",             limit: 1,   default: false, null: false
  end
```

result

```
create_table "results", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user_email", limit: 255
    t.integer  "result",     limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end
```

please help me!

Comment: help    me   if someone read my query please

Answer (score 0):

Have you set relationship between user model and result model? Can you explain more detail? Basically, If you want to get data from another model to a model, I think you have to set relationship for 2 models.

Comment: i defined a belongs to assocations between these two model